# MVC views are displaying _Layout even when I don't specify them

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5

Perhaps I'm just having a bad day.

MVC views seem to be displaying `_Layout.cshtml` even when I do not specify layout. Is it defaulted somewhere?

The page in question is my `KeywordAdmin.cshtml` partial view which looks like this (this is the file in its entirety):

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            Test column 1
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            Test column 2
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            Test column 3
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I navigate to localhost/Keyword/KeywordAdmin I see this with the header and footer defined in `_Layout.cshtml`. If I wanted it to use that layout, I would have specified it.

Answer (score 0):

The layout system is in place for helping you keep things uniform. Based on your statement, it seems you'd prefer not leverage it, which you can do too.

Look in _ViewStart.cshtml within the Views folder.

If KeywordAdmin.cshtml is within a subfolder, you may have another _ViewStart.cshtml in that folder which would take precedence.

If you set Layout = ""; you'll go without the layout. If KeywordAdmin.cshtml is just an oddball item and it shouldn't use your normal layout, it would be recommended to add to the top of KeywordAdmin.cshtml:

```
@{ 
   Layout = ""; 
}
```

If you're wanting to leverage MVC in a way that meets your previous expectations, I'd recommend setting at the top of _ViewStart.cshtml:

```
@{
  Layout = ""; // most likely "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml" right now
}
```

and then on any pages where you do wish to leverage the layout, adding:

```
@{ 
   Layout = "~Views/Path.../LayoutName.cshtml"; 
}
```